# How to get the skipped blanks (original tokens without skipping)?

Tags: java, antlr4, dsl

g4：

```
grammar KBDP;
WS: [\r\n \t] -> skip;

VARNAME:[_a-zA-Z0-9]+;
OP:[='*,.];
REALVAR:'@' VARNAME; 

prog:sqlsentece+;
sqlsentece:'"' (VARNAME|OP|REALVAR)+'"';
```

original sql:

> "select * from myTables"

```
public void enterSqlsentece(KBDPParser.SqlsenteceContext ctx) 
    { 
        ctx.getText();
    }
```

`ctx.getText()` returns the tokens skipped blanks

> "select*frommyTables"

.

How can I get the original sql "select * from myTables" (with blanks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each parse context has a start and an end token which point to the tokens which comprise this context. A token has, among other properties, start + end indexes, which indicate the character offset in the original source stream. Use the associated CharStream and it's getText(Interval(from, to)); method to get the original text for a context.

Example:

```
public void enterSqlsentece(KBDPParser.SqlsenteceContext ctx) 
{
  CharStream cs = ctx.start.getTokenSource().getInputStream();
  String originalText = cs.getText(Interval.of(ctx.start.getStartIndex(), ctx.stop.getStopIndex()));
}
```

Comment: Could I trouble you to post the specific code?I'm sorry about this excessive demand,because I'm junior on both Java and Antlr4,thank you very much

Comment: Thank you  very much for your help ：)

Comment: @MarkMa, if my answer helped you then please accept it (the checkmark on the left). If you find it worth you can also upvote it (the up-arrow on the left), which awards extra points to me.

Comment: ,I'm really really sorry about that the stackoverflow point me less than 15 reputation to accept your answer.I will accept it later when  my   reputation more than 15,I promise .thanks for your help once again.Em...it seems the Votes cast are recorded,but don't display (the number of accpet are not changed).